# Packed masking in SSE

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, sse

I need to build some kind of masking system for a packed single because I need to use packed operations on vectors that contain less than 4 elements.

So, for example, I need to do something like this:

```
section .data

align 16 
a:      dd      1.5, 2.3, 5.0
align 16
x:      dd      1.0, -3.0, 5.0

global  main

main:   start

     movaps     xmm0, [x]
     movaps     xmm1, [a]
     addps      xmm0, xmm1
     haddps     xmm0, xmm0
     haddps     xmm0, xmm0
```

and this should lead to having in `xmm0`

> 11.8, 11.8, 11.8, 11.8

so that I can just take one of them to have the result of my operation.

This is needed because the code should work on user's input, which may not contain a multiple of 4 elements and, instead of writing a special case to handle it, I'd like to reuse the same code that I already have with just some slight changes.

From what I understand, in this case moving `a` to `xmm0` will end up in having in `xmm0`

> 1.5, 2.3, 5.0, 0.0

so there shouldn't be any kind of issue because adding 0 doesn't change anything.

But what if `a` was a `float*` passed from a `C` program? From what I understand I would have great chances of having a value different from `0.0` as the fourth element copied in `xmm0`, since I'm copying from the memory instead of working on a defined constant.

Of course this will mess up all my computations, leading to unwanted results, so here's my idea: can I "mask" the content of `xmm0` based on how many elements I have in?

This means that, in this case, I would've to manually set to 0 only the fourth element of `xmm0`, since the first three are needed.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
section .data

align 16 
a:      dd      1.5, 2.3, 5.0, 7.0
align 16
x:      dd      1.0, -3.0, 5.0, 7.0
align 16
mask:   dd      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF

section .bss

section .text

global  main

main:   start

        movaps      xmm0, [x]
        movaps      xmm1, [a]
        movaps      xmm2, [mask]    ; move the mask to a support registry

        cmpnltps    xmm3, xmm2      ; this compare should put -NaN where xmm2 has 0xFF
        andps       xmm0, xmm3      ; mask x vector     
        andps       xmm1, xmm3      ; mask a vector

        ; let's make the needed operations to compute the result
        addps       xmm0, xmm1      
        haddps      xmm0, xmm0
        haddps      xmm0, xmm0

        ; yay! there's 11.8, 11.8, 11.8, 11.8 in xmm0!

        stop
```

I've tried a few examples and it works fine as I need, even if I change the mask to exclude some other values (`0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF` will work on the first 2 elements only etc.).

Now, given that I started working with `SSE` a few days ago, I'm not sure that this is the correct way to do it, and I can't think to some kind of examples to prove that it doesn't work, so here's the question: is there any better/official way to achieve what I need and, if not, does my code do the job or does it works just because I'm using one "lucky" example?

Comment: Why not just make `mask` ready to use without a compare - put `0xffffffff` in each non-masked element and 0 in the masked elements, and then `and` this with the data to zero any unwanted elements ? No need for compares, NaNs, etc.

Comment: So basically this will end up in having something like 
`mask: dd  0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0x00, 0x00
andps  xmm0, [mask]`, right? EDIT: I tried it and it works, if you post the edited code as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Exactly. I'm a little busy right now, but feel free to go ahead and write this up as an answer and accept it for the sake of posterity - I'll come back later and up-vote it!

Comment: I'll do it in one hour if you don't post it yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this C-code with gcc-vector extensions,

```
typedef float v4sf __attribute__((vector_size(16)));

v4sf foo(float const *restrict a, float const *restrict b)
{
  float const *restrict aa = __builtin_assume_aligned(a, 16);
  float const *restrict ba = __builtin_assume_aligned(b, 16);
  v4sf av = *(v4sf*)aa;
  v4sf bv = *(v4sf*)ba;
  v4sf sv = av+bv;
  float temp = sv[0]+sv[1]+sv[2];
  v4sf ret = {temp,temp,temp,temp};
  return ret;
}
```

`gcc -Ofast -S` generates the following assembly (AT&T-syntax):

```
foo:
    movaps  (%rsi), %xmm1       #load 1 of the vectors
    addps   (%rdi), %xmm1       #load the 2.nd vector, add to 1.st
    movaps  %xmm1, %xmm0        #make a copy of the sum
    movaps  %xmm1, %xmm2        #make a second copy
    shufps  $85, %xmm1, %xmm0   #shuffle [3][2][1][0] to [1][1][1][1]
    unpckhps    %xmm1, %xmm1    #unpack [3][2][1][0] to [3][3][2][2]
    addss   %xmm2, %xmm0        #add [3][2][1][0] to [1][1][1][1]
    addss   %xmm1, %xmm0        #add [3][3][2][2] to [3+1][2+1][1+1][0+1]
    shufps  $0, %xmm0, %xmm0    #shuffle [0+1+2] to all positions
    ret
```

Avoiding the need to load a constant mask from memory.

Comment: Can you please explain what this code does? I'm still learning SSE.

Comment: @StepTNT: I've added some comments.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Do you think that this is faster than loading the mask and doing just a `andps reg, mask` ?

Comment: @StepTNT: You'd have to measure. I *suspect* that it'll be faster, and if you compile for a modern x86 micro-architecture (with AVX2 in particular) you can probably get the compiler to produce even better code, for free.